# NextAuth User Password implementation does work how?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

im trying to implement user authentification with NextAuth with email only. I want to make users register an account, get an account verification mail and register them. This seems to be most convenient for me doing it with NextAuth. Im following this guide here: https://blog.logrocket.com/building-authorization-api-next-js/

Using Next Auth, a postgresql database (with prisma) and JWT. Now following the guide and setting up the email provider

```
// pages/api/auth/[…nextauth].js
// ...other imports
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'

const options = {
  site: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
  providers: [
    Providers.Email({
      server: {
        port: 465,
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        secure: true,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
        },
        tls: {
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
        },
      },
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    })
  ],
  database: process.env.DATABASE_URL
}
```

Im pretty new to this so please dont offend me asking this question, but im wondering how to login then? In the guide they say we will get a confirmation email if we sign up first time and then we have our session. But what if the user wants to log in later on? He never defined any password. Is it the correct way to ask for a password in registration step and save the hashed version with bcrypt in the database, then confirmation email will be sent and next login works with password login?

Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's by design, I'll quote [from the docs](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/email):

> The Email provider uses email to send "magic links" that can be used
> to sign in, you will likely have seen these if you have used services
> like Slack before.

So no, there's no password involved with that provider: if you implement just that users will have to re-insert their e-mail again, get a fresh magic link and login with that for their session.

What you're looking for, by the sound of it, is the [Credentials Provider](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials):

> The Credentials provider allows you to handle signing in with
> arbitrary credentials, such as a username and password, domain, or two
> factor authentication or hardware device (e.g. YubiKey U2F / FIDO).
>
> It is intended to support use cases where you have an existing system
> you need to authenticate users against.

You'll find several examples on how to integrate that with a custom backend, here's a few off the first Google results (not mine, can't really personally guarantee for any of them, just take a look and go from there!):

- https://dev.to/twisha/using-credentials-provider-with-a-custom-backend-in-nextauth-js-43k4
- https://dev.to/dawnind/authentication-with-credentials-using-next-auth-and-mongodb-part-1-m38
- https://blog.boardiesitsolutions.com/implementing-credentials-provider-on-nextjs-and-nextauth/

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing things up! Could you also provide me a source how to add email confirmation there?